# Nell'italiano corrente cosa significa "Le vene 'a mossa"? culumbrina?

Tags: regional, phrases

*Le vene ’a mossa* - È una frase che appare in una vecchia canzone napoletana *’O russo e ’a rossa* di Renato Carosone

’o russo, quanno vede ’a rossa
Le vene ’a tosse
’a rossa, quanno vede ’o russo
Le vene ’a mossa.
Chella fa ’a culumbrina

Comment: Al di là del significato letterale del testo, è non meno importante il modo in cui suona, con tutte quelle consonanze (cioè rime imperfette in cui sono mantenute uguali le consonanti): russo - rossa - tosse - mossa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il significato di "le viene la mossa" fa riferimento all'invenzione di [Maria Campi](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maria_Campi), la cui vita viene liberamente raccontata nel film [Ninì Tirabusciò, la donna che inventò la mossa](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nin%C3%AC_Tirabusci%C3%B2,_la_donna_che_invent%C3%B2_la_mossa).

> Dotata di bellezza molto vistosa, mandava in visibilio il pubblico con
> la sua celebre "**mossa**" e, soprattutto, con motti romaneschi piuttosto
> salaci, attraverso i quali soleva interloquire con gli spettatori,
> durante l'esecuzione delle sue canzoni piccanti, spesso suggeriti da
> Petrolini, Alfredo Bambi e Trilussa, suoi fraterni amici.

Dalla trama del film si può leggere:

> Maria si lancia sul palcoscenico e canta la famosa canzone "Ninì
> Tirabusciò", con un testo riadattato per il suo temperamento
> battagliero. L'esibizione è un grande successo, soprattutto perché
> durante la canzone inventa la "mossa", un movimento delle anche molto azzardato
> per l'epoca, che cattura subito l'attenzione del pubblico maschile

È quindi il riferimento al particolare movimento delle anche che per l'epoca era molto osé. Al giorno d'oggi probabilmente la mossa non sarebbe considerata così audace come all'epoca, visto cosa si vede in TV.

Per quanto riguarda il termine **[culumbrina](https://wally48.blogspot.com/2015/02/proverbi-e-dintorni-indovina.html)**, esso significa donna di facili costumi o quanto meno, come suol dirsi, "farfallina".

> Donna Culumbrina, è un personaggio femminile presente non solo nel
> salento, ma un po' in tutto il meridione ed in particolar modo in
> Campania. Mentre donna Tennerina, rappresenta la ragazza giovane in
> cerca di marito, molto pudica, delicata e sensibile che è attenta a
> non scomporsi, Donna Culumbrina ne è il suo opposto.
>
> È una donna sposata che trae la sua origine dalla maschera chiamata
> Colombina, magari avanti negli anni che non vuole arrendersi all'
> avanzare dell' età, perciò si veste e si comporta, pur non avendone
> più le caratteristiche,  come un' adolescente civettuola e frivola a
> volte scatenando la gelosia ed attirandosi le ire del marito o
> fidanzato che sia, infatti a Napoli la frase *nun fa 'a Culumbrina*
> risuona come rimprovero e minaccia.

Comment: Puoi dire che fai un movimento della danza della pância?

Comment: Non è propriamente la danza del ventre. È proprio la mossa... Se cerchi su YouTube puoi trovare molti filmati da cui puoi capire oggettivamente meglio il significato

Comment: Sto traducendo la canzone in portoghese da mettere sul mio sito web e devo trovare la parola esatta. Anche in spagnolo, inglese. e l'italiano attuale

Comment: Per lo spagnolo ti potrebbe sicuramente aiutare @Charo

Comment: Veramente, non saprei come tradurre tutto questo in spagnolo, abarisone!

Comment: Questo è per te   https://italiasempre.com/vedere/vedere_musica.php?ver=it&vedere=orussoearossa1 e questa è per @Charo https://italiasempre.com/vedere/vedere_musica.php?ver=es&vedere=orussoearossa3

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo, non credo che tu possa tradurre letteralmente "la mossa"; "la mossa" è  la definizione che è stata data ad un gesto ben preciso e, tradotta, perderebbe il suo significato. Penso che il meglio che tu possa fare sia sostituire "la mossa" con un termine generico di significato analogo; ad esempio potresti usare "ancheggiamento", per usare un termine descrittivo del gesto, o "moina" se invece vuoi usare un termine descrittivo dell'intenzione (sedurre, affascinare).

Comment: @secan, dopo che abarisone ha spiegato l'origine del termine mossa sono riuscito a trovare la parola in portoghese che fa capire alle persone cosa significa la mossa (movimento sensuale)